# Perl SOAP::Lite XML Parser encoding value

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, soap, character-encoding

I am calling web service with SOAP::Lite. It gives following error:

```
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 7, column 16, byte 281 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187
```

At line 7 of output, there is Turkish character which I think caused this problem. I can see output from terminal. It is starting with following line :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

There is no encoding parameter. How can I set output encoding value to UTF-8?
I tried following when I am calling web service but it did not work:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', @_ } )
    -> readable(1)
    -> uri('xxx')
    -> proxy("http://xxx")
    -> ns("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","soapenv")
    -> ns("xxx","yyy");
$soap->serializer()->encodingStyle("utf-8");
```

Comment: Your XML prolog seems correct for UTF-8, because a missing encoding attribute implies UTF-8 already. Guessing the turkish character as the problem doesn't help much, you shoud additionally provide the XML context reaching the server, so especially line 7 completely and the bytes for the turkish character.

Comment: XML input context reaching to server is correct because when I call web service at debug mode (use SOAP::Lite 'debug'), I see context at logs and it works when I copy it to SOAPUI interface it works.

Comment: Output context is as follow :  

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyMethodOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/xxx/MyMethod">
      <P_SONUCTXT></P_SONUCTXT>
      <P_SONUC>Bilgi: KIOS olumsuz</P_SONUC>
      <P_RENK>Ye�il</P_RENK>
      <P_KARARSTATU></P_KARARSTATU>
      <P_KARARSONUC></P_KARARSONUC>
      <P_FAIZ>0</P_FAIZ>
    </MyMethodOutput>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Line 7 at output is as follow:

 <P_RENK>Ye�il</P_RENK>

Comment: Provides the bytes of column 16 as HEX. And if your logged request works in SoapUI, check the HTTP headers sent using SOAP::Lite.

Comment: How will I chech HTTP headers? I see following when I call web service at debug mode : 

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Response=HASH(0x9219db4)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Oracle XML DB/Oracle Database
Content-Type: text/xml
Client-Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2016 11:50:22 GMT
Client-Peer: 172.22.36.108:8080
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DAV: 1,2,<http://www.oracle.com/xdb/webdav/props>
MS-Author-Via: DAV

Comment: You need some tool like Wireshark showing you the exact request sent by your client.

Comment: @thorsten, I am also client and seeing xml code making request. It works when I copy it to SOAPUI. It can not be a coincidence that the error message indicates to line 7 ( <P_RENK>Ye�il</P_RENK>) at response. There is not any other Turkish character before it.

Comment: I still could not find a solution. How can I set response encoding to iso-1859  instead of default value utf-8?